# How do I use SSO (single sign on) With Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-roles

I have MVC web application that use roles in Authorization , Now i want to use SSO with it and other applications that may or may not use roles
I try simple implementation for SSO

```
<machineKey validationKey="E4451576F51E0562D91A1748DF7AB3027FEF3C2CCAC46D
  756C833E1AF20C7BAEFFACF97C7081ADA4648918E0B56BF27D1699A6EB2D9B6967A562CAD14767F163"

              decryptionKey="6159C46C9E288028ED26F5A65CED7317A83CB3485DE8C592"

              validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
```

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="SingleSignOn"

  loginUrl="http://localhost/SSO/Account/Login"

  timeout="480" slidingExpiration="true">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="demo"

      password="89e495e7941cf9e40e6980d14a16bf023ccd4c91"/>
      <!--password = demo-->
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

I follow this steps [LINK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1140228/Implementation-of-Single-Sign-On-SSO-in-ASP-NET-MV?msg=5686232#xx5686232xx)

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, Error I ask about the way i could use user roles that already in my users tables in my site DB ? @RyanNerd